# Laravel - voyager BREAD

Tags: php, laravel, posts, voyager

I started my simple laravel project with posts. First I created my auth, than my posts and everything works fine. But I installed voyager admin panel(without dummy) in my project and I add BREAD to posts table, but when I try to Edit some of my posts it shows me an error: `Call to undefined method App\Post::getTranslationsOf() (View: C:\engineering\xampp\htdocs\lsappdev\vendor\tcg\voyager\resources\views\posts\edit-add.blade.php)`. Why is this error showing?
Here is my `PostsController`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use App\Post;
use DB;

class PostsController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['index', 'show']]);
    }


    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::all();
        return view('posts.index')->with('posts', $posts);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('posts.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
            'cover_image' => 'image|nullable|max:1999'
        ]);

        // Handle File Upload
        if($request->hasFile('cover_image')){
            // Get filename with the extension
            $filenameWithExt = $request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalName();
            // Get just filename
            $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            // Get just ext
            $extension = $request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            // Filename to store
            $fileNameToStore= $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
            // Upload Image
            $path = $request->file('cover_image')->storeAs('public/cover_images', $fileNameToStore);
        } else {
            $fileNameToStore = 'noimage.jpg';
        }

        $post = new Post;
        $post->title = $request->input('title');
        $post->description = $request->input('title');
        $post->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $post->cover_image = $fileNameToStore;
        $post->save();

        return redirect('/posts');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);
        return view('posts.show')->with('post', $post);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);

        //Check if post exists before deleting
        if (!isset($post)){
            return redirect('/posts')->with('error', 'No Post Found');
        }

        // Check for correct user
        if(auth()->user()->id !==$post->user_id){
            return redirect('/posts')->with('error', 'Unauthorized Page');
        }


        return view('posts.edit')->with('post', $post);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required',
            'body' => 'required',
            'cover_image' => 'image|nullable|max:1999'
        ]);

        $post = Post::find($id);
         // Handle File Upload
        if($request->hasFile('cover_image')){
            // Get filename with the extension
            $filenameWithExt = $request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalName();
            // Get just filename
            $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            // Get just ext
            $extension = $request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            // Filename to store
            $fileNameToStore= $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
            // Upload Image
            $path = $request->file('cover_image')->storeAs('public/cover_images', $fileNameToStore);
            // Delete file if exists
            Storage::delete('public/cover_images/'.$post->cover_image);
        }

        $post->title = $request->input('title');
        $post->body = $request->input('description');
        if($request->hasFile('cover_image')){
            $post->cover_image = $fileNameToStore;
        }
        $post->save();

        return 123;
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);

        //Check if post exists before deleting
        if (!isset($post)){
            return redirect('/posts')->with('error', 'No Post Found');
        }

        // Check for correct user
        if(auth()->user()->id !==$post->user_id){
            return redirect('/posts')->with('error', 'Unauthorized Page');
        }

        if($post->cover_image != 'noimage.jpg'){
            // Delete Image
            Storage::delete('public/cover_images/'.$post->cover_image);
        }

        $post->delete();
        return redirect('/posts');
    }
}
```

And here is my `Post.php` model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Laravelista\Comments\Commentable;

class Post extends Model
{
    use Commentable;

    protected $table = 'posts';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = ['title', 'description', 'cover_image', 'user_id'];

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Please if anybody know a solution for this error help! Everything worked fine before I installed Voyager in my project.

Comment: You need to overwrite your `view` see [this](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/issues/3628#issuecomment-436997869).

Answer (score 2):

You are using the voyager model. So in your post model  at the top

```
Use  \TCG\Voyager\Traits\Translatable;
```

And inside braces

```
Use Translatable;
```

Hope it helps